# Mapping non-entity class variable names, as in javax.persistence.metamodel

Tags: java

It is possible to map variable names for a non-entity class, as in the following example?

```
import javax.persistence.metamodel.SingularAttribute;
import javax.persistence.metamodel.StaticMetamodel;

@StaticMetamodel(MyEntity.class)
public class MyEntity_ {

    public static volatile SingularAttribute<MyEntity, Long> id;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<MyEntity, String> firstField;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<MyEntity, Boolean> secondField;

}
```

And get variable name, ex. MyEntity_.firstField.getName();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Lombok project and @FieldNameConstants annotation can help.

More details can be found at:
https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/FieldNameConstants